# How do you enable Microsoft Terminal Service Client Control in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, activex, rdp

I found this article on how to setup and use RDP client for MFC.  But where do you get the dialog they show in step 2?   Here's the link to [RDP Remote Desktop ActiveX Controls](https://www.programmersought.com/article/65123148481/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found one way to do it, open the toolbox window, right-click, "choose items" and it brings up that dialog to choose the various components.   I never knew any of that existed.